# opening and saving file without save/open dialogue

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i would like to do FILE I/O without a dialogue. the file always be the same and the location will always be the same, therefore i dont need a dialogue. i would like to know how can i do this? what is the code to open, write, and save to a file without the dialogue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialogue does not open a file.  It selects a file for open or save. It's still up to the app to open or create the file that was selected.

[Basic File I/O in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336wast5.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The easist way to do this in vb.net is system.io.file.create.  For more information check out the members of the [system.io.file class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_members.aspx)