# Opening a dynamically created Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, savefiledialog

I have a Windows Forms app with an Excel file I created using [SpreadsheetGear](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/). My application uses `SaveFileDialog()` to prompt the user to save the file to their computer using the following code:

```
'Bring up the save dialog to save the newly created Excel file
Using saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "ExportFile.xlsx"
    If DialogResult.OK <> saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        e.Result.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
End Using
```

That code works fine but the user doesn't want to worry about saving the file. He just wants it to open right away so he can copy/paste the information he needs and then discard the file without having to navigate to his save destination. I can't seem to get `SaveFileDialog()` to do that for me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which part isn't working, though?

Comment: @rlb.usa - The code above works, it just doesn't open the file. I need to be able to open the file automatically after saving, or skip the `SaveFileDialog()` altogether and open it without saving.

Comment: does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page I know that you want the browser to open the local file but I'm really pretty sure that isn't possible (think of the malicious applications to that!) and that the best you can do is produce a link on the screen saying to "click here" and that opens the `file:///`

Comment: @rlb.usa - This is a Windows Forms app, not website so that question doesn't help much.

Comment: My apologies! How about [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685260/open-a-file-without-dialog), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263077/opening-and-saving-file-without-save-open-dialogue?rq=1)

Comment: @rlb.usa - This one got me where I needed to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362716/opening-an-excel-file-from-button-click-on-a-windows-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362716/opening-an-excel-file-from-button-click-on-a-windows-form) helped me discover my answer. `Process.Start` with the filename from the `SaveFileDialog` works.

Updated Code:

```
'Bring up the save dialog to save the newly created Excel file
Using saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "ExportFile.xlsx"
    If DialogResult.OK <> saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        e.Result.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook)

        If File.Exists(saveFileDialog1.FileName) Then
                Process.Start(saveFileDialog1.FileName) 'Open the newly created Excel file
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Could not find file to open. Please try again.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
End Using
```